# What does the option passed at the end of the Systemd command mean?

Tags: options, systemctl

I have this ***command***:

```
systemctl restart rh-php71-php-fpm -l
```

I would like to know what the `-l` which is passed at the end of the command corresponds to?

Comment: did you look at the man page of `systemctl` yet?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, i found nothing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man systemctl`:

> -l, --full
>
> Do not ellipsize unit names, process tree entries, journal output, or truncate unit descriptions in the output of status,
> list-units, list-jobs, and list-timers.
>
> Also, show installation targets in the output of is-enabled.

So what it means, that the output is not cut off at the end. Usually, the output is shortened to make it more legible.